# Playing random songs algorithm

Tags: algorithm, random

Wondering what is the best way to solve this problem: Random play a song from a list of given songs in such a way that no songs is repeated until all the songs are played.

My algorithm basically calls get_random with the reduced set of music sets to find out the next song to play. get_random uses power of 2 to divide the list and then further sub-dividing.

Is this the best I can do or any other better algorithms I can come up with? I need just the idea.

```
import random
import math

def get_random(number):
        if number == 0:
            return number
        if number == 1:
            return number
        #make the number power of 2
        orig_no = number
        number = 1 << (math.floor(math.log(number))+1)
        left = 0
        right = number
    # check if toss falls in this current half and then change the half for next recursion. 
    # we change half from 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 36, 64, 128
        while left < right:
          #f1 can be replaced by this rd.randint(0, 1)
            toss_value = f1() 
            if toss_value:
                right = math.floor((left + right)/2)
            else:
                left = math.floor((left + right)/2) + 1
        if left >= orig_no:
            return get_random(orig_no)
        else:
            return left

songs = ["i am here", "your are beautiful", "soorry", "i am happy", "where am i", "what did i do", "nothing wrong with you"]
for i in range(0, len(songs)-1):
        value = get_random(len(songs))
        print(songs[value])
        songs.pop(value)
```

Comment: This is probably not what you want as it is not a algorithm. but you can just use a random int to get a song from your arrays and then store the int in another array and just check if the new random int is in the arrray and if it is get a new random int.

Comment: So I'm guessing you are looking to devise such an algorith on your own, and not just use language libraries? Because if you want to do the latter, Python already has random.shuffle(). I think doing an in-place rearrangement is ideal here, as it lets you conveniently look ahead.

Comment: Looks overly complicated. Why not just generate a random number between in [0 .. n-1] if there are n songs in the list.

Comment: I just want to know if this is how it is done. Basically call random function and use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shuffle the array of songs, play all the songs, and shuffle it again....

You can use [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to shuffle the array. Since you are using Python, there's already [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) for you.